# Horizontal Scroll View Width in Android?

Tags: android

How can I set a width for Horizontal Scroll View?

```
myHorizontalScrollView.setWidth();
```

This doesnt appear to work, I need to limit the scroll views width.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT
        ,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
myHScrollView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

You can set the width and height using the layout parameters object.

To set exact number as width you need to use the TypedValue class

```
int value = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 
                 (float) 200, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

And the int should be set in the LayoutParams constructor.

Comment: But how do I specify a width? I want it to be 200px wide

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(width ,height);
myHScrollView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Also you can set width and height to `wrap_content` and `fill_parent`

Comment: Does not work, I want to set the width of the scroll view, so it's smaller that the content inside it. This just puts the scroll view into another smaller view

Answer (score 0):

Set your scrollview to fill the parent's width and make that parent 200dp wide